# How the user knows what languages the application supports?

Tags: ios, swift, localization

I am learning about localization and when I search about how to change the language programmatically from inside the application, mostly I found that "linking the system Settings through your application".

**Problem:** If I link Settings through my application, that settings language gives me all languages that iOS supports, BUT how does the user know which languages the application supports or what is the best way to show the user which languages they can pick?

**For example:** My application supports English and Russian. In my application I have a button like "choose language" and the user presses it and redirects them to system Settings. Then the user, for example, chooses French which my application DOES NOT SUPPORT.

Another question would be: if the system language is English but the user wants only my application to be Russian (NOT WHOLE SYSTEM LANGUAGE!), how could we achieve this?

Maybe when I list English and Russian on a screen and when the user taps any of those, it doesn't link Settings and asks user to choose language again BUT it automatically changes the system language to what we selected. Any ways to do this?

Comment: Just let the user choose the language for your app in the settings app. In the settings for your app in the settings app it will show only the languages that your app supports. Do not provide any language settings in your app itself. It is unnecessary.

Comment: if user chooses any language that your project does not support from iPhone language settings, it will display what did your write in the string. For example: loginLabel.text = "_login".localized it will be _login

Comment: @Paulw11 Yes you were right! I thought it shows main screen of settings, but it shows directly settings for my app and YES it only shows language which only my app supports. THANK YOU!!!